# How to find the most frequently used JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have a project with a lot of inter-related files that require each other. I want to know which is the most frequently used dependency (JS file) excluding npm modules, with each use defined as a 'require' or 'import' statement from the dependent file.

Example: I have common methods stored in `src/general/utils.js`, and is imported by multiple files throughout my application. As such, that would be my most frequently used file `utils.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things first.

It's important to note that the `import` command is not native to `nodeJS`. Rather it's a feature provided by transpilers such as those used by `webpack`, all of which will convert `import` commands into the NodeJS supported `require()` provided by node's internal `Module` module.

Under the covers, `Module.require()` uses a cache to hold all previously required modules to optimize requires so they are only included once.

To your question, one approach to counting modules loaded by the nodeJS runtime would be to override the portion of `require()` that locates and loads required modules either from internal sources (like `events`, `fs`, etc.), the file system (for first time requires), or the require cache (for subsequent requires of already loaded modules).

This can be accomplished by creating and requiring the following module as the first require used by your application:

```
// filename: module-override.js
const Module = require('module')

Module.MODULES = {
  LOADED: {},
  CACHED: {}
}
Module.__load = Module._load // save original _load()

Module._load = function (request, parent, isMain) { // redefine _load()
  const filename = Module._resolveFilename(request, parent, isMain)
  const key = filename.replace(/^\/Users\/USERNAME/, '...')
  if (!key.match(/node_modules/)) { // ignore paths with node_modules
    let val
    if (Module._cache[filename]) { // exists in Module_cache
      val = Module.MODULES.CACHED[key] || 0
      Module.MODULES.CACHED[key] = val + 1
    }
    val = Module.MODULES.LOADED[key] || 0
    Module.MODULES.LOADED[key] = val + 1
  }
  return Module.__load(request, parent, isMain) // the original _load()
}
```

Note: You can comment out the line which defines the `key`. I added that so the output of stringifying `Module.MODULES` did not contain any locally identifying information.

Once you require this module, it will collect a count of all required modules in `Module.MODULES`.

`Module.MODULES.LOADED` will keep track of how many times a module has been required while `Module.MODULES.CACHED` will do the same for requires that have been fulfilled from the internal module cache.

Assume that I have two modules under `./lib` named `utils.js` and `Schedule.js` where

- `./lib/utils` requires `util`, `path`, `events`, `debug`, `json-stringify-safe` and`lodash`, and
- `Schedule.js` requires `path`, `colors` and `./lib/utils`

And that I have a top-level file that requires both `./lib/Schedule` and `./lib/utils`.

After all the requires have completed, I can then call

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Module.MODULES))
```

which will print to the console:

```
{ 
  LOADED: {
    '..././lib/Schedule.js': 1,
     path: 2,
     '..././lib/utils.js': 2,
     util: 2,
     events: 1,
     tty: 1
   },
  CACHED: {
    '..././lib/utils.js': 1
  }
}
```

which tells me that

- `./lib/Schedule.js` was loaded once from the file system,
- `path`, `util`, `events`, and `tty` were loaded from nodeJS's internal modules, and
- `utils` was loaded twice, once from its file and once from the internal require cache

Without the test to weed out all modules found under `/node_modules/` the output will be:

```
{
  LOADED: {
    '.../lib/Schedule.js': 1,
    path: 2,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/index.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js': 6,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/styles.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/system/supports-colors.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/custom/trap.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/custom/zalgo.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/maps/america.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/maps/zebra.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/maps/rainbow.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/maps/random.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/extendStringPrototype.js': 1,
    '.../lib/utils.js': 2,
    util: 2,
    events: 1,
    '/.../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js': 1,
    '/.../node_modules/json-stringify-safe/stringify.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/debug/src/index.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/debug/src/node.js': 1,
    tty: 1,
    '.../node_modules/debug/src/debug.js': 1,
    '.../node_modules/ms/index.js': 1,
    '/.../node_modules/supports-color/index.js': 1 },
  CACHED: {
    '.../node_modules/colors/lib/colors.js': 5,
    '.../lib/utils.js': 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, solid answer. It would be a nice project to create a webpack plugin based on your code, similar to the various webpack bundle analyzers that are available.